# Why is this true: A graph is bipartite if and only if $\beta_1(G)>= \frac{1}{2}|V(H)|$

Tags: graph-theory

Show that a graph $G$  is a bipartite if and only if $\beta_1(H) \ge \frac{1}{2}|V(H)| $for every subgraph $H$ of $G$.

$V(H)$ is the set of vertices of $G$.

where $\beta_1(G)$ is a maximum independent  number of edges of G.

Comment: What is $\beta_1(G)$?

Comment: @fatemeh: The more you take the time to explain your notation the greater the chance that someone will take the time to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that “maximum independent number of edges” is the same as “maximum number of  independent edges” and the graph $G$ has no loops and multiple edges, we can easily prove the required characterization.

If the graph $G$ is bipartite, so is its each subgraph $H$. Let $V(H)=V_1\cup V_2$ be the bipartition of vertices of $H$. Let $V_i$ be the smallest of these sets. Then $|V_i|\le |V(H)|/2$. Since each edge of $H$ is incident to a vertex of $V_i$, by pigeonhole principle, a family of independent edges of $H$ may have size at most $|V_i|\le |V(H)|/2$.

Conversely, assume that $\beta_1(H) \ge \frac{1}{2}|V(H)| $for every subgraph $H$ of $G$. Then $G$ cannot have a simple cycle $H$ of odd length as a subgraph, because this would imply $\beta_1(H)= \frac{1}{2}(|V(H)|-1)$, a contradiction. Thus the graph $G$ is bipartite.